# how to shorten a change view function in android

Tags: android, performance, android-layout

i got a function which goes like this. the main purpose of this method is to switch layouts inside the same layout to avoid different activities

```
protected void SchermWisselen(int i) {
    if (i == -1) {
        this.finish();
    }
    if (i == OpstartScherm) {
        VorigeScherm = -1;
        // opstart scherm
        lblDLCKeuze.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        listAparaatSelecteren.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        btnRefresh.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        // hoofdmenu scherm
        HOL.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        tglWissel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        RGLijnen.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        btnMode.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        btnToonStatus.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        btnTijden.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        SKWaarde.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        txtStream.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        txtWaarde.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        txtInvoerWisselen.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        tglWissel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        // Tijden versturen scherm
        txtZetTijd.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        txtUur.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        txtInvoerUur.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        txtMinuut.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        txtInvoerMinuut.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        txtLijn0.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        txtLijn1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        SKLijn0.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        SKLijn1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        spnNummerSelecteren.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        btnVerstTijd.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        btnMassa.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        // Discovery scherm
        btnDiscoveryZoeken.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        lvDiscoveryResultaten.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        lblDiscoveryTonen.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        // Commando Sturen
        txtCommandosInvoer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        txtCommandoUitvoer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        // Status tonen
        btnSyncKlok.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        btnSyncDag.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        btnCommando.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        btnParameters.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        btnGrafiek.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        btnAstroData.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        txtToonStatus.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        // grafiek
        lnGrafiek.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    if (i == HoofdMenu) {
        VorigeScherm = -1;
        //brute force
        GeOpend = false;
        // opstart scherm
        lblDLCKeuze.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        listAparaatSelecteren.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        btnRefresh.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        // hoofdmenu scherm
        HOL.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        tglWissel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        RGLijnen.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        btnMode.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        btnToonStatus.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        btnTijden.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        SKWaarde.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        txtStream.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        txtWaarde.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        txtInvoerWisselen.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        // Tijden versturen scherm
        txtZetTijd.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        txtUur.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        txtInvoerUur.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        txtMinuut.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        txtInvoerMinuut.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        txtLijn0.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        txtLijn1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        SKLijn0.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        SKLijn1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        spnNummerSelecteren.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        btnVerstTijd.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        btnMassa.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        // Discovery scherm
        btnDiscoveryZoeken.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        lvDiscoveryResultaten.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        lblDiscoveryTonen.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        // Commando Sturen
        txtCommandosInvoer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        txtCommandoUitvoer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        // Status tonen
        btnSyncKlok.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        btnSyncDag.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        btnCommando.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        btnParameters.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        btnGrafiek.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        btnAstroData.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        txtToonStatus.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        // grafiek
        lnGrafiek.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
```

this feels like a lot of rinse and repeat which isn't as good as it could be

Comment: I recommand to read this guide to use Fragments: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html, with abstraction for Fragments that have similar functionnalities

Comment: use Fragment UI and put them in LinearLayout if you want

Comment: thanks for the comment but i am using api lvl 10 which does not support fragments :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put all views that you want to hide into one container, for example a FrameLayout with a id, and then hide that id.

But I would really recommend another approach like fragments (there is the support fragment manager for older versions).